# using boto in pycharm

Tags: import, pycharm, boto

I am installed boto using pip and am able to run the boto in command line terminal in my mac OSX. However when I am trying to import the boto in pycharm, it is not working.

Could'nt find on how to get the path and import. Appreciate any possible help here. Thanks

Comment: Is your pycharm project configured to use the same interpreter that you installed boto in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as Jordon Phillips suggests, check if in Pycharm you are using the same interpreter.

You can simply check this in Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter.

If it is not the same, select the correct one and try.

Otherwise, if it is already the same, try to uninstall from pip and reinstall it directly in Pycharm.

Go to Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter, select the correct one and press the plus icon on the right corner of the window.

After this try to use it as usual.

Please let me know.